# How to use vtkHardwareSelector?

Tags: vtk, qvtkwidget

I am building a simple tool for manipulating point clouds.  I want to be able to do  do a polygonal selection on mouse move. 
I am working with VTK 5.10 and QVTKWidget in Ubuntu 12.04.

To do this, I built a polygonalSelector class by modifying the test file : TestPolygonSelection.cxx at https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/Rendering/Core/Testing/Cxx/TestPolygonSelection.cxx
The modifications are those needed to use VTK 5.10 instead of vtk 6 as described here : (note that I need to use the old version) http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/VTK_6_Migration/Replacement_of_SetInput

In the code, a polygonal shape is drawn and then a vtkHardwareSelector object `vtkNew<vtkHardwareSelector> hardSel;` is used for its method of GeneratePolygonSelection:

The problem I am running into is when the next condition is tested :

`if (hardSel->CaptureBuffers())`

Internally, CaptureBuffers() contains code that does this:

```
  vtkRenderWindow *rwin = this->Renderer->GetRenderWindow();
  int rgba[4];
  rwin->GetColorBufferSizes(rgba);
  if (rgba[0] < 8 || rgba[1] < 8 || rgba[2] < 8)
  {
    vtkErrorMacro("Color buffer depth must be atleast 8 bit. "
      "Currently: " << rgba[0] << ", " << rgba[1] << ", " <<rgba[2]);
    return false;
  }
```

I never get past this point because it always returns false. I have no clue how to set the ColorBufferSizes and I have not been able to find info online to clear this point. 
This is the error output:

```
  vtkHardwareSelector (0x168dcd0): Color buffer depth must be atleast 8 bit. Currently: 17727456, 0, 23649488
```

On debugging, the rgba int is never changed (it stays the same before and after the call to `rwin->GetColorBufferSizes(rgba)` ).

On the Documentation for vtkRenderWindow it states that :

```
virtual int vtkRenderWindow::GetColorBufferSizes    (   int *   rgba    )
Get the size of the color buffer. Returns 0 if not able to determine otherwise sets R G B and A into buffer.

Implemented in vtkOpenGLRenderWindow, and vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.
```

Do I need to use  vtkOpenGLRenderWindow?
On its Class reference it states that "Application programmers should normally use vtkRenderWindow instead of the OpenGL specific version."

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I believe the problem stems from the VTK 5.10 vs VTK 6 differences.

I did manage to implement the polygonal selection using a different approach.
If anyone intends to implement some kind of polygonal selection in the future, they might find these steps useful:

I sub-classed vtkInteractorStyleDrawPolygon and implemented the following steps inside the OnLeftButtonUp() method:

1. Get points on button release: `std::vector<vtkVector2i> points = this->GetPolygonPoints();`
2. Insert points to vtkDoubleArray
3. Insert the vtkDoubleArray into a vtkPolygon
4. Get the polygon's numPoints, normal and bounds.
5. Get pointer to the double array inside the polygon data pts.

   ```
   pts = static_cast<double*>(polygon->GetPoints()->GetData()->GetVoidPointer(0);
   ```
6. For each point P in the vtkPolyData, do :

   ```
   inside = polygon->PointInPolygon(P,numPoints, pts, bounds,normal)
   ```
7. Add points to a vtkSelection when inside == 1

Comment: I have not tried, but I see in the documentation a link to vtkScenePicker , where they say: "This class uses a vtkHardwareSelector under the hood. Hence, it will work only for actors that have opaque geomerty and are rendered by a vtkPolyDataMapper." . Could it be the problem?

Comment: You can also try the other tests  in http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/5.10/html/c2_vtk_t_7.html#c2_vtk_t_vtkHardwareSelector , the links are broken but you find the same files in your source tree

Comment: I read the note about opaque geometry and the Poly Data requirements. I think what I do should not cause any problem, but thanks!. I'll check the other version of the tests to see if there is any significant difference.